# Cant install Ray library for Reinforcement Learning on python 3.8.12

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray

I want to install ray library on python **3.8.12** version **1.0.1**. I could install version **0.8** on python **3.7** but I need version **1.0.1** or **newer one**. I get the error as follows:

****ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ray (from versions: none)***

***ERROR: No matching distribution found for ray****

I am using python on Mac. I used anaconda but I have not got any solution.

Comment: use pip install ray

Comment: I used that but that doesn't work also

Comment: what error do you get as it works.